# Sending Database dropdown & jQuery DatePicker data to a mySQL Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have encountered a problem recently and I am unable to solve it. I have a client booking form, where they get a dropdown menu which is connected to a database with treatments etc. that displays all the data, and I also have a jQuery DatePicker, and further plans to implement a jQuery TimePicker very soon.

When I try to submit the form to be updated to a mySQL Database, none of the data comes through. It doesn't even show up as an array whey I `var_dump($_POST)` the whole thing. Also I have a textarea, it says the data goes through, but it doesn't actually appear in the database.

Here is the `var_dump($_POST)`:

[image]

Here is the database dropdown **PHP** code:

```
<!-- All database connection stuff followed by the following: -->

$query = "SELECT * FROM `Treatments`";

$result = mysql_query($query, $con);
$options = "";

if (!$result){
    die("No results found.");
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $options .= "<option>$row[1]</option>";
}


?>
```

And here is what gets inserted into my Database:
- I have the DataTypes in mySQL set as `DATE` for Date and `TIME` for Time -

[image]

Here is my **PHP**:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);

$hostname = 'hostname';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$con=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db($dbname,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

$insert = "INSERT INTO Booking_request_form (Treatment, Date, Time, Message) VALUES('".$_POST["Treatment"]."','".$_POST["Date"]."', '".$_POST["Time"]."', '".$_POST["Message"]."')";

var_dump($insert);
$handle = mysql_query($insert);
var_dump($handle);

?>
```

And here is my **HTML** form: 
 
I have commented out the TimePicker because it didn't work for me.

```
<form action="treatment_form.php" method="post"> 
    <div class="heading1">
        <p>Select Your Treatment:</p>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <select><?php echo $options; ?></select>
    </div>

    <div class="heading2">
        <p>Select Your Date:</p>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
                <script>
                $(function() {
                    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
                });
                </script>
    </div>

    <div class="heading3">
        <p>Select Your Time:</p>
            <input type="text" id="timepicker"/>
            <!-- <script>
            $(function($) {
                $(function() {
                    $('input.timepicker').timepicker();
                });
            })(jQuery);
            </script> -->
    </div>

    <div class="heading4">
        <p>Add a message for our Staff:</p>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Enter Message..."></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Request Booking" id="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you have to give `name` to the input fields `<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date"/>`

Comment: @SearchAndResQ Let me try :)

Comment: do not use mysql_* . They are completely removed in PHP7 .

Comment: @Drudge Yes I know, I will change that soon.

Comment: and check this too: [Keywords and Reserved Words in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). The field names `date` and `time` could cause problems.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ Will do, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide name attribute to following elements like :

```
1. <input type="text" id="datepicker  name="date_attr"/>
2. <input type="text" id="timepicker"  name="time_attr"/>
3. <div class="dropdown">
        <select name="treatment"><?php echo $options; ?></select>
    </div>
```

then try to print $_POST variable

Ok, format date & time before insert:

```
1) $_POST['date_attr'] to date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date_attr']))
2) $_POST['time_attr'] to date('H:i:s',strtotime($_POST['time_attr']))
```

Comment: Yes that works, it does show they are getting added, but the database doesn't show the time's added, all it prints is: `0000-00-00`. Are my DataTypes in mySQL right?

Comment: Yes just checking. My `$_POST` is written like this: `'".$_POST["Date"]."'`. Where about would I implement the time and date format?

Comment: `INSERT INTO Booking_request_form (Treatment, Date, Time, Message) VALUES('".$_POST["Treatment"]."','".date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST["Date"]))."', '".date('H:i:s',strtotime($_POST["Time"]))."', '".$_POST["Message"]."');`

Comment: @Filip Like this way

Comment: Thats awesome thanks. Give my question a thumbs up if its going to be helpful to other people :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing **name**  in your input fiedls. PHP takes html forms values from **name** attribute of HTML see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)  doc . Try the below code and try to print $_POST variable . Hope this help .Happy coding :)

Select Your Treatment:

```
        <div class="dropdown">
            <select name="option">
<?php echo $options; ?>
</select>
        </div>

        <div class="heading2">
            <p>Select Your Date:</p>
                <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date"/>
                    <script>
                    $(function() {
                        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
                    });
                    </script>
        </div>

        <div class="heading3">
            <p>Select Your Time:</p>
                <input type="text" id="timepicker" name="time"/>
                <!-- <script>
                $(function($) {
                    $(function() {
                        $('input.timepicker').timepicker();
                    });
                })(jQuery);
                </script> -->
        </div>

        <div class="heading4">
            <p>Add a message for our Staff:</p>
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Enter Message..."></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Request Booking" id="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks you :) Do you by any chance know how to fix the jQuery TimePicker?

Comment: The PHP yes :) The jQuery, no.